# How to select from a collection?

Tags: sql, orientdb

For exemple I run this query :

```
select classes from metadata:schema
```

My problem is that I get only one row representing the list of the classes.

How could I make it return a row for each class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `unwind`, e.g.:

```
select classes from metadata:schema unwind classes
```

`unwind` is worth remembering, e.g. because currently (version 2.1) it is not always possible to compose functions such as `expand`; also, one can `unwind` several result-sets at once using the syntax: `unwind COL1, COL2, ...`

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
select expand(classes) from metadata:schema
```